# Rails speed up database with code refactor for process remover

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I've got worker class which removes `InquiryProcess` older than `x time` (default should be set to 6 months). Potentially it will be a large data scale so is there any chance to speed up deletions with code below?

```
class OldProcessRemover
  def initialize(date: 6.months.ago)
    @date = date
  end

  attr_reader :date

  def call
    remove_loan
    remove_checking_account
  end

  private

  def remove_loan
    loan_template = InquiryTemplate.find_by(inquiry_process_name: InquiryTemplate::LOAN_APPLICATION_PROCESS_NAME)
    loan_template.inquiry_processes.where('created_at <= ?', date).each(&:destroy)
  end

  def remove_checking_account
    checking_account_template = InquiryTemplate.find_by(
      inquiry_process_name: InquiryTemplate::CHECKING_ACCOUNT_OPENING_PROCESS_NAME,
    )
    checking_account_template.inquiry_processes.where('created_at <= ?', date).each(&:destroy)
  end
end
```

Maybe somewhere I could use `find_in_batches` ?. I don't think these methods are single responsibility, so refactor will helped either.

Comment: Do you actually need to `destroy` the records or would it be possible to just `delete` them? Are there callbacks, counter_caches or validations in place that need to run?

Comment: @spickermann Unfortunately yes, I have to use `destroy` to avoid `PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR`

Comment: Could you not use ON DESTROY CASCADE in you foreign key.  Then you might be able to do this all on the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
class OldProcessRemover
  def initialize(date: 6.months.ago)
    @date = date
  end

  attr_reader :date

  def call
    remove_loan
    remove_checking_account
  end

  private

  def remove_loan
    remove_processes!(InquiryTemplate::LOAN_APPLICATION_PROCESS_NAME)
  end

  def remove_checking_account
    remove_processes!(InquiryTemplate::CHECKING_ACCOUNT_OPENING_PROCESS_NAME)
  end

  def remove_processes!(process_name)
    account_template = InquiryTemplate.find_by(
      inquiry_process_name: process_name
    )
    account_template.inquiry_processes
                    .where('created_at <= ?', date)
                    .find_in_batches { |group| group.destroy_all }
  end
end
```

I don't think there is any major difference between using `.find_in_batches { |group| group.destroy_all }` or `.find_each {|record| record.destroy }` here.